# how does IServiceScopeFactory get registered internally?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

below is some code example using DI:

```
public class Program {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var services = new ServiceCollection();                

      services.AddScoped<IXXX, XXX>();    
 
      ServiceProvider rootContainer = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);    

      using (IServiceScope scope = rootContainer.CreateScope) { /
         IXXX sth= scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<XXX>();  
      }
   }
}
```

and the source code of `CreateScope()` is

```
public static class ServiceProviderServiceExtensions {
   // ...
   public static IServiceScope CreateScope(this IServiceProvider provider) {
      return provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();   
   }
}
```

how does `IServiceScopeFactory` get registered? and what is the concrete implementation for `IServiceScopeFactory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does `IServiceScopeFactory` get registered?

It is registered internally within the `ServiceProvider` when it is initialised.

```
//...

CallSiteFactory.Add(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory), new ConstantCallSite(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory), Root));

//...
```

[Source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs,48)

> and what is the concrete implementation for `IServiceScopeFactory`?

In the above registration, the `Root` is a property

```
internal ServiceProviderEngineScope Root { get; }
```

[Source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs,31)

of the internal type `ServiceProviderEngineScope`

```
internal sealed class ServiceProviderEngineScope : IServiceScope, IServiceProvider, IAsyncDisposable, IServiceScopeFactory
```

[Source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceProviderEngineScope.cs,12)